# T-SQL Script unconsitant in running time. Why?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, scripting, performance

I've got this script that runs on a SQL Server Express 2008 machine.

```
/* BUD501T */
declare @ErrMsg      nvarchar(4000)
declare @ErrLine    nvarchar(100)
declare @currentFY nvarchar(1000)
declare @programName nvarchar(1000)

set @ErrMsg = ''
set @ErrLine = ''
set @programName = 'BUDPROD - GL_Exp.sql'
select @currentFY = value from Budgets.dbo.Config where [key] = 'current_fy';


/* GL EXP */

/*Log*/
EXEC [Budgets].dbo.Log_SP @program = @programName ,@message = 'Starting';

--Status
UPDATE [Budgets].[dbo].[Status]
SET [start] = GETDATE()
WHERE [name] = @programName;



BEGIN TRY
--Delete fy
DELETE FROM [Budgets].[dbo].[GL_Exp] WHERE fiscal_year = @currentFY;


--Insert fy
WITH ledger_detail AS (
  SELECT pld.fiscal_year,
        pld.accounting_period,
         pld.financial_deptid AS DEPTID, 
         pld.fund_code,
         pld.class_fld AS CLASS_CODE, 
         pld.project_id,
         pld.program_code,
         CASE
           WHEN pld.account IN ('500020','520000','520220','520240') THEN 2
           WHEN LEFT(pld.account,1) = '5' THEN 1
           WHEN LEFT(pld.account,1) = '6' THEN 3
           WHEN LEFT(pld.account,1) = '7' THEN 4
           WHEN LEFT(pld.account,1) = '8' THEN 5
           ELSE 0
         END AS ACCT_GRP_CODE,
         pld.budget_amount,
         pld.encumbrance_amount,
         pld.expenditure_amount,
         pld.account AS ACCOUNT_CODE, 
         CASE
           WHEN LEFT(pld.class_fld, 2) ='12' THEN 0
           WHEN LEFT(pld.class_fld, 3)='113' THEN 3
           WHEN LEFT(pld.class_fld, 3)='112' THEN 14
           WHEN LEFT(pld.class_fld, 3)='115' THEN 10
           WHEN LEFT(pld.class_fld, 3)='116' THEN 13
           WHEN LEFT(pld.class_fld, 3)='117' THEN 12
           WHEN LEFT(pld.class_fld, 3)='118' THEN 11
           WHEN LEFT(pld.class_fld, 2)='13' THEN 2
           WHEN LEFT(pld.class_fld, 2)='14' THEN 3
           WHEN LEFT(pld.class_fld, 1)='4' THEN 4
           WHEN LEFT(pld.class_fld, 1)='6' THEN 6
           ELSE 9
         END AS FUND_SOURCE 
    FROM [DWPROD]..[DISC].[PS_LEDGER_DETAIL] pld
   WHERE pld.budget_period = @currentFY
     AND pld.accounting_period BETWEEN 1 AND 12
     AND pld.fiscal_year = 2010
     AND pld.financial_deptid BETWEEN '100' AND '999'
     AND pld.account BETWEEN '500000' AND '899999')

     INSERT INTO [Budgets].[dbo].GL_Exp (fiscal_year, accounting_period, entity_code, division_code, deptid, fund_code, class_code, project_id, program_code, acct_grp_code, account_code, gl_bud_amt, gl_enc_amt, gl_exp_amt, fund_source)
      SELECT
      x.FISCAL_YEAR,
      x.accounting_period,
      y.strdepentity AS ENTITY_CODE,
      y.depdiv1 AS DIVISION_CODE,
      x.deptid, 
      x.fund_code,
      x.class_code,
      x.project_id,
      x.program_code,
      x.acct_grp_code,
      x.account_code AS ACCOUNT_CODE, 
      SUM(x.budget_amount) AS GL_BUD_AMT, 
      SUM(x.encumbrance_amount) AS GL_ENC_AMT, 
      SUM(x.expenditure_amount) AS GL_EXP_AMT,
      x.fund_source
 FROM ledger_detail x
LEFT JOIN [Budgets].[dbo].[Departments] y ON y.deporg = x.deptid    
 GROUP BY x.fiscal_year, x.accounting_period, y.strdepentity, y.depdiv1, x.deptid,     x.fund_code, x.class_code, x.project_id, x.program_code, x.acct_grp_code, x.ACCOUNT_CODE,x.FUND_SOURCE
 ORDER BY x.deptid, x.class_code, x.project_id, x.account_code;



--Fixes
--Set rundate
 UPDATE [Budgets].[dbo].[GL_Exp] SET RUNDATE = GETDATE()
               WHERE (FISCAL_YEAR=@currentFY);


--Set OB amount NOT WORKING
UPDATE x
SET BU_ORIG_BUD_AMT = ob.OB_AMT
FROM [Budgets].[dbo].[GL_Exp] x INNER JOIN [Budgets].[dbo].[OrigBudSumm_VW] ob on  x.FISCAL_YEAR = ob.FISCAL_YEAR AND x.ACCOUNT_CODE = ob.ACCOUNT_CODE AND x.PROJECT_ID = ob.PROJECT_ID
WHERE x.FISCAL_YEAR=@currentFY;

UPDATE [Budgets].[dbo].GL_Exp
SET bu_orig_bud_amt = ISNULL(bu_orig_bud_amt, 0)
WHERE fiscal_year = @currentFY;

--Fix Fringes, changes acct_grp_code on flat rate fringes
UPDATE [Budgets].[dbo].[GL_Exp] SET ACCT_GRP_CODE = '0' 
            WHERE FISCAL_YEAR= @currentFY AND 
             DEPTID='890' AND GL_BUD_AMT<0 ;

UPDATE [Budgets].[dbo].[GL_Exp] SET ACCT_GRP_CODE = '0'
            WHERE FISCAL_YEAR= @currentFY AND DEPTID='894'  ;


UPDATE [Budgets].[dbo].[GL_Exp] SET ACCT_GRP_CODE = '2A' 
            WHERE FISCAL_YEAR= @currentFY AND acct_grp_code='2' And class_code Like '%05';

UPDATE [Budgets].[dbo].[GL_Exp] SET ACCT_GRP_CODE = '2A'
            WHERE FISCAL_YEAR= @currentFY AND acct_grp_code='2' And class_code Like '4%';

UPDATE [Budgets].[dbo].[GL_Exp] SET ACCT_GRP_CODE = '2A' 
            WHERE FISCAL_YEAR= @currentFY AND acct_grp_code='2' And class_code Like '12%';


--Status
UPDATE [Budgets].[dbo].[Status]
SET [status] = 'Ran', [end] = GETDATE()
WHERE [name] = @programName;

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
select @errMsg      = error_message(), @ErrLine = 'Line: ' + cast(ERROR_LINE() as nvarchar(100));
EXEC [Budgets].dbo.Log_SP @program = @programName,@message = @ErrMsg, @errorlevel = 'Error', @location =  @ErrLine;
UPDATE [Budgets].[dbo].[Status]
    SET [status] = 'Error',
    [end] = GETDATE(),
    [error_message] = @ErrLine + ' - ' + @ErrMsg
    WHERE [name] = @programName;
END CATCH;


  /*Log*/
EXEC [Budgets].dbo.Log_SP @program = @programName,@message = 'Finished';
```

It's long but pretty simple. It clears out a table and inserts updated information, then it does some fixes on the data for our use. It inserts about 200,000 rows of data in the main insert.

My problem is that sometimes this thing will run in about 6 minutes and other times it will run in about 20 min and sometimes it will run in about 2 hrs. I can't peg it down and I've let it run for about a week (it's scheduled to run daily at 5:15 am). Now it does hit some linked servers but I have other jobs that hit the same linked servers and they are consitant, unlike this.

So my question is what's going on? Is it running out of memory (this is the Express version after all)? Can I tell if the linked servers are slowing it down? Is there something wrong with the query?

Thanks,
Clint

Comment: Are you running other queries at the same time which may lock the relevant tables?

Comment: No, they are each run one at a time because they depend on the order run. And at this time in the morning nothing else is going on.

Comment: @JonSeigel - If you're going to edit messages, don't mess up the formatting of the post. Lucky I caught this one that you messed up.

Comment: I did not touch the code, but sometimes the formatter goes haywire on existing posts. My apologies for not checking after the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could activate [SET STATISTICS TIME ON](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190287.aspx) as well as [SET STATISTICS IO ON](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184361.aspx).

`STATISTICS TIME` will give you information about which SQL statement requires how much time. This should let you pinpoint whether there is one particular statement that is causing trouble or whether the overall performance is slow.

`STATISTICS IO` will tell you how much IO access is performed. If you see large variations here, it could mean that either SQL Server caching is not working well or that sub-optimal execution plans are used every now and then.

In addition, you could have [SQL Server Performance Counters](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/tips/sql_server_performance_monitor_coutners_p1.aspx) running in the background. Afterwards, you can check if there exists a correlation between slow and fast performance and specific performance counter values. This allows you to verify whether this is a memory issue or not.

Answer (score 2):

You need to take a look at your execution plan and statistics. Here is an article that might help get you started - [Execution Plan Basics](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/execution-plan-basics/)